# Shopify manage products quantity after checkout

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm a bit new to Shopify, and i would like to know if there are some ways to update product quantities in the inventory after a purchase of a product. (Without using any Apps) I have Shopify Debut theme.
I would like to do something like this for example:

**Product A purchased ? ->   (Product_A_quantity - 1) && (Product_B_quantity - 2)**

I haven't been able to find something that could help me yet, and i hope someone could help me with that.

Thank you in advance,

Valentin.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But assuming you mean your sold a quantity of 1 of product A, and somehow you want Shopify to decrement product B by 2, the short answer is, you use API calls per order, or you do this manually. No reasonable system will do what you want without some guidance.